# how to get value of field in jquery jtable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jtable

I have a `drop-down` in `j-table` and I want to extract the `selected value` from it. Is there any way to get the `selected option` values from j-table.

```js
sections_template_id: {
  title: 'Template',
  inputTitle: "Template*",
  options: web_sections,
  create: true,
  edit: true,
  list: true                
}
, sec_hidden: {
type: 'hidden'
  , inputTitle: "Template*"
  , create: true
  , edit: false
  , list: false
  , defaultValue: web_sections
   }
```

i want to set the value of `sections_template_id` in `sec_hidden`

this is my route on which i am calling a function

```
 Route::post('cms-web-section-templates',['as' => 'cms-web-section-templates', 'uses' => 'CmsController@Main_sections']);
```

and here is my function

```
public function Main_sections(Request $request)
    {
        $types = SectionType::getTypes();

      $web_section = WebTemplate::all();

     //dd($web_section);

        $rows[] = array("DisplayText"=>"", "Value"=>"");

        foreach ($web_section as $key => $web_sections) {
            $rows[] = array(
                'DisplayText' => $web_sections->name,
                'Value' => $web_sections->id,
            );
        }

        $this->response['Options'] = $rows;
        $this->response['Result'] = "OK";
        return json_encode($this->response);
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example of your code?

Comment: @obscure i did edit my question kindly if u can help me

Comment: can you show the table and dropdown selection.

Comment: @user10971804 its a lengthy code to post ..

sections_template_id: {
  title: 'Template',
  inputTitle: "Template*",
  options: web_sections,
  create: true,
  edit: true,
  list: true                
}

this is selection of section of which id i want to get

Comment: Just get the data by its selectID like this `$('#selectID').on('change',function(){ var value = $(this).val();})` . This will still work if the selector is a class.

Answer (score 0):

I used jquery/javascript to grab data from `jtable`. I cant find in the jtable documentation how to grab the selected value. If you inspect element, once you select the row, a class is added in that row which is "jtable-row-selected".

```
<script>
        var all_rows = [];
        $('tr.jtable-row-selected').each(function(){
            var len = $(this).children().length;
            var row = [];
            for(let i = 0;i < len; i+=1){
                row.push($(this).children()[i].innerText)
            }
            all_rows.push(row);
        })
        //console.log(all_rows);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the jtable `selectedRows` method to get a jquery object of the selected rows.

The documentation https://jtable.org/ApiReference/Methods#met-selectedRows has short worked example how to get the record and fields for each selected row.